# How to setup fixtures for ArrayCollection at entity constructor in NelmioAlice

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures, nelmio-alice

I have read and tried all the things described in [this](https://github.com/nelmio/alice#specifying-constructor-arguments) section of docs but I can't get this working. This is the constructor at entity:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->targets = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->targetBrand = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And I tried to bypass using `__construct: false` but get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]
>     Unable to parse at line 11 (near " name: ").

This is how the fixtures looks like:

```
\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Brand:
    # 3 Brand per Company
    brand{1..3}:
       __construct: false
       name: <name()>
       generic_name: <name()>
       logo_url: <imageUrl(128,128)>
       description: <paragraph()>
       isi_required: <boolean(35)>
       isi_text: <realText()>
       isi_pdf_url: <url()>
       pi_required: <boolean(35)>
       pi_text: <realText()>
       pi_pdf_url: <url()>
       inactive: <boolean(35)>
       company: @company*
       createdAt: <dateTimeThisYear()>
       updatedAt: <dateTimeThisYear()>
```

If I not set `__construct` then the error turns into this other:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object 
>   given, called in /var/www/html/reptooln_admin/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 555 and defined

What is wrong? How I should setup the fixture?

**EDIT:**

I have found [this](https://github.com/nelmio/alice/issues/114) but how I can use that approach on the fixture I am trying to setup, can any give me some advice?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm a little confused because `Brand` is mapped to `TargetBrand` entity and `TargetBrand` is inversed by `Brand` entity, see entities below:

```
class Brand
{
    // other class properties

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TargetBrand" , mappedBy="brand")
     */
    protected $targetBrand;

    protected $targets;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->targets = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->targetBrand = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // other class methods

    public function getTargets()
    {
        $targets = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->targetBrand as $target) {
            $targets[] = $target->getTarget();
        }

        return $targets;
    }

    public function setTargets($targets)
    {
        foreach ($targets as $target) {
            $targetBrand = new TargetBrand();
            $targetBrand->setBrand($this);
            $targetBrand->setTarget($target);
            $this->addTargetBrand($targetBrand);
        }
    }

    public function addTargetBrand($targetBrand)
    {
        $this->targetBrand[] = $targetBrand;
    }

    public function removeTargetBrand($targetBrand)
    {
        return $this->targetBrand->removeElement($targetBrand);
    }
}


class TargetBrand
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $priority;

    /**
     * @var Target
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Target", inversedBy="targetBrand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="targets_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    protected $target;

    /**
     * @var Brand
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", inversedBy="targetBrand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
    protected $brand;

    public function setPriority($priority)
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriority()
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    public function setTarget(Target $targets = null)
    {
        $this->target = $targets;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTarget()
    {
        return $this->target;
    }

    public function setBrand(Brand $brand)
    {
        $this->brand = $brand;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->brand;
    }
}
```

If I'm running the fixtures using a set as follow:

This is the set I mention before:

```
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Territory.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Representative.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/TargetBrand.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Target.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Brand.yml', 'yaml');

$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Company.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Media.yml', 'yaml');
$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Message.yml', 'yaml');

$set->addFile(__DIR__.'/Email.yml', 'yaml');
```

And setting `Brand` and `TargetBrand` fixtures as follow:

I got this error instead:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Catchable
>   Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TargetBrand::setTarget() must be an instance of
>   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Target, instance of
>   PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TargetBrand given, called in
>   /var/www/html/reptooln_admin/vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Loader/Base.php
>   on line 506 and defined

```
\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Brand:
    # 3 Brand per Company
    brand{1..3}:
       name: <name()>
       generic_name: <name()>
       logo_url: <imageUrl(128,128)>
       description: <paragraph()>
       isi_required: <boolean(35)>
       isi_text: <realText()>
       isi_pdf_url: <url()>
       pi_required: <boolean(35)>
       pi_text: <realText()>
       pi_pdf_url: <url()>
       inactive: <boolean(35)>
       company: @company*
       createdAt: <dateTimeThisYear()>
       updatedAt: <dateTimeThisYear()>
       targetBrand: @targetBrand*

\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TargetBrand:
  # 10000 TargetBrand
  targetBrand{1..1000}:
      priority: <randomDigitNotNull()>
      target: @target*
      brand: @brand*
```

Which is the right order to load fixtures on this case?

**NOTE:** `$targets` is not need anymore so do not take care of that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have setters defined, i.e. `setTarget()` and `setTargetBrand()` or `addTarget()` and `addTargetBrand()`, the following should work:

```
\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Brand:
    brand{1..3}:
       (define your brands)
\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Target:
    target{1..3}:
       (define your targets)
\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\TargetBrand:
    targetBrand{1..3}:
       target: @target<current()>
       brand: @brand<current()>

\PDI\PDOneBundle\Entity\Brand:
    brand{1..3}:
        (..other definitions...)
        targets: [@target1, @target2, @target3]
        targetBrand: [@targetBrand1, @targetBrand2, @targetBrand3]
```

Comment: Hmmm I'm a little confused, can you take a look to __EDIT 1__ at OP and tell me if your solution is the same having that entities mapping?

Comment: FYI, I'm getting the same issue with another entity with same behaviour

Comment: I'm looking at your edit, and your issue is likely in this line:  `target: @target*`. This matches both `@target*` and `@targetBrand*`. You can replace it with `target: @target<current()>`.

Comment: I'm not following you at all. I want to have 1..1000 `targetBrand` if I go through your solution and leaves `target: @target<current()>` then when it tries to create the `targetBrand` four I got this error `Reference brand4 is not defined` and of course this is because I am only creating 3 `Brand` how do I get ride of the issue but keeping the 1000 `TargetBrand`?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way to do this with AliceFixtures, I've had the same issue and ended up not using {1..3} notation and defining these things manually. If you're okay with cascading data, you can generate necessary amount of target brands in php, by adding a `public function targetBrands()` to your fixture Loader and using it in the fixture as `<targetBrand()>

Comment: Can you improve your answer adding something about your latest comment?

Answer (score 0):

for me adding related(many-to-many) object fixtures working that way

```
ordersServices: ['@service_*']
```